# CSS text.overflow with @Html.LabelFor

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to insert ellipsis at the end of a *@Html.LabelFor* when my bootstrap div column in too small.

If I use static text it appears correctly with

> Lorem ips...

displayed, but as soon as I use the *@Html.LabelFor* it just cuts it off as

> Lorem ips

without the ... at the end.

Herewith my code:-

```
    <style>
        .hideOverflow {
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 hideOverflow">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
@*                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Balloon)*@
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Balloon)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Balloon)
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.LabelFor` gets rendered as `<label>`
You should write your css for `<label>` not for `div`

Something like following

```
.hideOverflow label{
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        display: inline-block;
}
```